# How can I reverse the x-axis of this plot?

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the following plot:

[image]

I want to reverse the x-axis from 1 to 0, I try with some piece of code but that not run because only turn all the plot, I want to keep the points where they are, and only change the x-axis values.

How can I do it?

I am using the following code:

```
roc_df <- data.frame(
  fvp=rev(roc_obj$sensitivities),
  ffp=rev(1 - roc_obj$specificities))


plot(0:10/10, 0:10/10, type='n', xlab="ffp", ylab="fvp")
abline(h=0:10/10, col="lightblue")
abline(v=0:10/10, col="lightblue")
abline(coef = c(0,1), col="lightblue")
with(roc_df, {
  lines(ffp, fvp, type='l', lwd=1, col="blue")
  lines(ffp, fvp, type='b', lwd=1, col="blue")
})
```

Comment: you can try `df$ffp = 1- df$ffp`

Comment: Is this in base R? Just do a manual version of the x axis after plotting with the labels however you want them. See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/axis) for details.

Comment: @HubertL That not work, because turn the points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to get really specific when you haven't posted the data you're plotting, but I think you should be able to do this by turning off the x-axis when you initially make the plot, then manually adding it back with the labels the way you want them. Something like:

```
# generate your plot without an x-axis
plot(0:10/10, 0:10/10, type='n', xlab="ffp", ylab="fvp", xaxt= "n")
# put backthe x-axis, but with reversed labels
axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, 0.2), labels = rev(seq(0, 1, 0.2)))
# then pick up the rest of your code
```

You'll probably want to tune the aesthetics, but I think this is the only way to get labels that don't match the data.

Comment: No need to redo the y-axis, note in [`?plot.default`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.default.html) it says *"axes: ... Use graphical parameter '"xaxt"' or '"yaxt"' to suppress just one of the axes."* You can replace `axes=FALSE` with `xaxt="n"` (and then a single `axis(1,...)` call). (The help for `xaxt` is found at [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html).)

Comment: This works too: `plot(df, type = "b", xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.2), labels = seq(from = 1, to = 0, by = -0.2))`

Comment: @ulfelder: why `type="n"`? This suppresses plotting the points.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, I was just pasting OP's code there, but it looks like they are making an empty canvas first, then adding the points/lines back at the end.